# How to configure Groovy in a Java Module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, groovy, android-studio, module

I'm starting with the Android world and I need help..

First of all, sorry for my english :(

I already configure `groovy` in my "app" module and it works fine, but now I'd want to configure `Groovy` also a java-module (which is used in de "app" module)

I've tried to configure `groovy` in an in Android Studio but I didn't get it.

In the "build.gradle" of my module, I have this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.3:grooid'
}
```

And I have a Groovy class in this module:

[image: Groovy Class]

But when I try to run the App in the emulator, I get this error:

```
Error:(12, 46) error: cannot find symbol class OpMovidasG
```

If I use the `.java` classes, It works fine, but if I use a `.groovy` class, it breaks.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

There's a guide to configure Android Studio with Groovy in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30282538/3568838

You're missing a couple of things (dependencies, plugins, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is coming from years later...
I also wrote a gradle plugin project which is written in groovy.
Remember to add `apply plugin: 'maven'` to module-level `build.gradle`.
There is a good project you may refer to [here](https://github.com/goodbranch/Android-GradlePlugin-Demo).

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
    implementation localGroovy()
}
```